# Encountered two children with the same key REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBNs9.png)

New in react here. Coding without using div, however is a constant issue the duplicated array and I don't know how to fix it.

```
return (    

    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
   <Screen> 
    <FlatList
    data={messages} 
    keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString}
    renderItem={({item})=> 
    <ListItem
    title={item.title}
    subTitle={item.description}
    image={item.image}
    onPress={()=> console.log("Message selected", item)}
    renderRightActions={() => (<ListItemDeleteAction onPress={()=> handleDelete (item)}/>)}
    />}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}/> 
    </Screen>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `toString` is a function not a property so it will be with `undefined`, so all the items will have key with `undefined` and this is the cause of the error.

It should be

```
keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
```

Also, make sure that each `message` in `messages` array with unique `id`.